# Minimal models in strong set theories - pt. 2

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, model-theory

This is a follow-up to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4402379/minimal-models-in-strong-set-theories).

So, as Noah elucidated (thanks Noah!), whenever $T$ is r.e., $M(T) < \sigma$ ($\sigma$ is the least stable ordinal, i.e. $L_\sigma\prec_{\Sigma_1}L$).

In general, for a first-order set theory $T$ and an ordinal $\alpha$, we say $\alpha$ has $T$-structure iff $L_\alpha \models T$. The height of $T$ is the least ordinal w/ $T$-structure. Since a theory $T$ has to be consistent for any ordinal to have $T$-structure, we restrict ourselves to $\Pi^1_1$-sound theories in the following.

Now, the height of any r.e. theory is $< \sigma$ as I mentioned earlier. (By Lowenheim-Skolem, the height of *any theory* is $< \omega_1$). Here are my questions:

> Does $\sigma$ have $T$-structure for any r.e. first order set theory $T$?

I'm 99% sure the answer is yes. However, I'm less sure about the other question:

> For r.e. set theories $S, T$, let $\alpha$ and $\beta$ be their heights, respectively. If $\alpha < \beta$, does $T$ prove $S$'s consistency? If not, would the answer still be no if we restrict it so that $\beta$ has $S$-structure as well as $\alpha$?

I know some cases when this is true. For example, the height of KP set theory is less than that of ZFC, and ZFC proves KP's consistency (iirc).

Comment: You need much more assumptions on $T$. E.g , $T=\mathrm{ZFC+\neg Con_{ZFC}}$ is a consistent (if ZFC is consistent) r.e. first-order set theory, but it holds in no $L_\alpha$ whatsoever.

Comment: But anyway, it's certainly not true that all the models $L_\alpha$ are elementarily equivalent.  So pick any sentence $\phi$ that happens to be false in $L_\sigma$, but true in some other $L_\alpha$. Let $T$ be $\phi$ + whatever base axioms you want for the theory to qualify as "set theory". Then $T$ is an r.e. theory such that $\sigma$ doesn't "have $T$-structure".

Comment: @EmilJeřábek Fixed the assumptions on $T$, I think $\Pi^1_1$-soundness should work fine. Also, with the second comment, you're right: you got into that 1%! Would it be fixed by restricting that $L \models T$?

Comment: $L_\sigma$ is, by definition, a $\Sigma_1$ elementary substructure of $L$, and therefore satisfies all $\Pi_2$ sentences true in $L$, but I’m pretty sure it does not go any higher. So no, $L\models T$ is not enough, you really need $L_\sigma\models T$. Which of course makes the question a tautology.

Comment: Also, I don’t see how you got to $\Pi^1_1$-soundness. The $L_\alpha$ structures satisfy all true $\Pi^1_1$ statements, hence a theory true in $L_\alpha$ is consistent with the set of all true $\Pi^1_1$ statements, i.e., it is **$\mathbf{\Sigma^1_1}$-sound**. I don’t see why it should be $\Pi^1_1$-sound. On the other hand, I don’t see why either $\Sigma^1_1$-soundness or $\Pi^1_1$-soundness should imply the existence of a model of the form $L_\alpha$, or even the existence of any well-founded model whatsoever.

Comment: For an example of a different kind, $\mathrm{ZFC} + V \ne L$ is not true in any $L_\alpha$, but it does have a well-founded model (assuming ZFC has one), and it is $\Sigma^\infty_\infty$-sound (assuming ZFC is), as it is $\Sigma^\infty_\infty$-conservative over ZFC.

Comment: Also, what you are trying to do in the second question cannot possibly work. Let $S$ and $T$ be any theories with heights $\alpha<\beta$ (resp.). Then $S'=S+\mathrm{Con}_T$ still has height $\alpha$ (and is additionally true in $L_\beta$ if $S$ was).

Comment: @EmilJeřábek What do you mean by "cannot possibly work"? What can't work? After all, I know many examples of theories with higher heights proving the consistency of theories with lower heights.

Comment: Of course there are individual examples for which it does work. I mean that it does not work in general, under any reasonable restrictions on $S$ and $T$.

Comment: @Binary198 Emil's comment about $S+\textrm{Con}(T)$ seems to be about the converse, I believe I have a counterexample in the direction mentioned in your question. I do not know where to find relevant literature about your first question, so I don't think I have enough for a full answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Negative answer for the first question: $L$ satisfies KP+"there exists a stable ordinal" but $L_\sigma$ does not. This is r.e. because "there exists a stable ordinal" can be expressed by a single axiom: take a truth predicate $\mathrm{Sat}_{\Sigma_1}$ for $\Sigma_1$ formulae (maybe for example Lévy's $\mathrm{Stsf}^1$ suffices), and restrict all its unbounded quantifiers to $L$ (i.e. replace any instance of "$\exists x\ldots$" with "$\exists x(x\in L\land\ldots)$" and any instance of "$\forall x\ldots$" with "$\forall x(x\in L\land\ldots)$"), call this resulting predicate $\mathrm{Sat}^L_{\Sigma_1}$. Define a predicate $\mathrm{St}(\alpha)$ as $\forall(k\in\mathbb N)((k\mathrm{\;G}{\ddot{\mathrm o}}\mathrm{del}\textrm{-}\mathrm{codes\;a\;}\Sigma_1\mathrm{\;formula}\land\mathrm{Sat}^L_{\Sigma_1}(k)\implies L_\alpha\vDash k))$, then "there exists a stable ordinal" is $\exists\alpha(\mathrm{St}(\alpha))$.

Negative answer for the second question: Let $S$ be $\mathrm{KP}+\mathrm{Con}(\mathrm{ZFC})$ and $T$ be $\mathrm{ZFC}$. The heights of $S$ and $T$ are $\omega_1^{CK}$ and a much larger countable ordinal $<\sigma$ respectively, and both theories are $\Pi^1_1$-sound (assuming ZFC is $\Pi^1_1$-sound), however $T$ does not prove $S$ consistent by Goedel's second incompleteness theorem. (This may have been the example in Emil Jeřábek's comment, although I may have misinterpreted it as a refutation of the converse of the second question.)

---

Some justification on why $S$ doesn't prove $T$ consistent: it doesn't seem to follow immediately from Gödel's second incompleteness theorem or similar, and needs a bit more argumentation. (Consistency statements of theories including $\mathrm{Con}(\mathrm{ZFC})$ are not automatically unprovable in $\mathrm{ZFC}$, for example $\mathrm{ZFC}$ proves the consistency of the theory whose only axiom is $\mathrm{Con}(\mathrm{ZFC})$.) To construct a model of $\mathrm{ZFC}$ where $\mathrm{Con}(\mathrm{KP}+\mathrm{Con}(\mathrm{ZFC}))$ fails, take a model $\mathcal A$ of $\mathrm{ZFC}$ where $\mathrm{Con}(\mathrm{ZFC})$ fails. $\mathcal A$ satisfies "$\lnot\mathrm{Con}(\mathrm{ZFC})$ is a true $\Sigma^0_1$ sentence", and $\mathrm{ZFC}$ proves that $\mathrm{KP}$ proves every true $\Sigma^0_1$ sentence, so $\mathcal A$ satisfies "$\mathrm{KP}$ proves $\lnot\mathrm{Con}(\mathrm{ZFC})$". $\mathcal A$ is therefore a model of $\mathrm{ZFC}+\lnot\mathrm{Con}(\mathrm{KP}+\mathrm{Con}(\mathrm{ZFC}))$.

Comment: I don't understand how what you say regarding the first question is relevant to the question. Moreover, isn't the first question trivially true, as witnessed by $T=\emptyset$, since $L_\sigma\models T$ then? (Or am I misunderstanding the question?)

Comment: @FarmerS The way I had read the question was with a universal quantifier, as "for any r.e., $\Pi^1_1$-sound first-order set theory $T$, does $L_\sigma\vDash T$" rather than "is there an r.e., $\Pi^1_1$-sound first-order set theory $T$, does $L_\sigma\vDash T$".

Comment: I see. What does $\Pi^1_1$-sound mean? And what is "a (first-order) set theory"?

Comment: @FarmerS I am assuming a first-order set theory $T$ here means a theory of first-order logic with relation symbol $\in$, perhaps with a requirement that $T$ must contain some basic axioms such as extensionality. (I am not sure if this restriction is present or what axioms are required, though both KP and ZFC seem to satisfy the necessary requirements. Binary198 may be able to specify in more detail what requirements $T$ must satisfy.) (continued)

Comment: $T$ is $\Pi^1_1$-sound if any $\Pi^1_1$ consequence of $T$ is true, this property appears in some literature on proof-theoretic ordinal analysis (e.g. Rathjen's "[The Realm of Ordinal Analysis](https://www1.maths.leeds.ac.uk/~rathjen/realm.pdf)"), where it is called $\Pi^1_1$-faithfulness.